# Mockito: replace method that throws an exception

Tags: java, mockito

I've this interface:

```
public interface IEnd<T> {
    T get() throws FluentApiException;
}

public interface IFluentEntityCollectionRelation<ID, T> extends IEnd<Iterable<T>>
```

I'm trying to mock this interface in order to return an concrete empty `Iterable<T>` object when it's called:

```
IFluentEntityCollectionRelation<String, Plan> plans = any();
when(plans.get()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Plan>());
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting a compilation error:

> Unhandled exception type FluentApiException

since `IEnd<>.get()` throws an `FluentApiException` exception never catched.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Simple: you should only need to change your test code like

```
@Test
public void testWhatever() throws FluentApiException
```

Of course, the testcase should never throw that exception. If it gets thrown, it will lead to a test case failure.

In other words: you simply don't care. Make the *compiler* happy by adding this checked exception to the test method(s) that invoke `get()`.

Comment: It missed the java tag.